# Node CLI program writeFileSync gets "EAGAIN" error when output redirected to a pipe

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, pipe

I've got a simple Node program used from the command line for testing an external API. The tool works in general: it makes an API call as per command line arguments and flags, does minor processing on the returned content (JSON), and then writes the result to standard output. The output goes through the following small utility:

```
const output = (function() {
    let accum = "";

    return {
        add(content) {
            accum += content;
        },
        lpad(indent) {
            this.add(indent ? new Array(indent + 1).join(" ") : "");
        },
        nl() {
            this.add("\n");
        },
        write() {
            writeFileSync(1, accum);
        },
        reset() {
            accum = "";
        }
    };
})();
```

That builds up an accumulation of calls to `.add()` and `.lpad()` etc into a string, and then the last thing the program does is call `.write()`, which uses `writeFileSync()` to write that string to standard out. That latter function is imported:

```
import { writeFileSync } from "fs";
```

Everything works fine when the standard out is not redirected (i.e., the terminal window). It also works fine when I redirect to a file. However, if I run the program and pipe output to `grep` or whatever, I get:

```
node:fs:939
  handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
  ^

Error: EAGAIN: resource temporarily unavailable, write
    at Object.writeSync (node:fs:939:3)
    at writeFileSync (node:fs:2301:26)
    at Object.write (file:///Users/m5/nodestuff/node_modules/nscall/src/output.mjs:20:13)
    at commit (file:///Users/m5/nodestuff/node_modules/nscall/src/output.mjs:109:12)
    at file:///Users/m5/nodestuff/node_modules/nscall/nscall.js:49:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errno: -35,
  syscall: 'write',
  code: 'EAGAIN'
}

Node.js v20.1.0
```

That error happens after some output makes it through the pipe.

The accumulated content can be somewhat large, but not many megabytes large. Intuitively it's like things break when the OS pipe buffer stalls, but it confuses me that `writeFileSync()` would have a problem with that. This is happening on MacOS, a platform that I'm not super familiar with, but on Linux and UNIX I've written countless similar tools over the years and the low-level filesystem `write()` call deals with the nature of the output kind-of transparently except in exotic cases (I guess; and a pipe is hardly exotic).

I'm really not a Node expert, so it maybe that this is something that falls into the category of examples about why sticking to the async APIs is a better idea. Still seems weird though.

*edit* — if I change the output `write` method to use the callback `write()` API, I don't get the error:

```
        async write() {
            const buf = Buffer.from(accum, "UTF-8");
            return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
                write(1, buf, function() {
                    res();
                });
            });
        },
```

I'm fine with leaving it like that but it's still weird.

Comment: In re: using async APIs, I can't figure out how you'd get a `FileHandle` instance for the standard output file descriptor; there does not seem to be an API for that in the Promises version of `fs`.